# Excel VBA Overflow Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line in Excel VBA:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(r, 1).Value = IIf(rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value = 0, "--", FormatPercent(rs2.Fields("SoldCallsQTD").Value / rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value, 2))
```

When I run the macro in Excel I get a "Run-time error '6': Overflow" error.

I know there is the possibility of getting a 0 value in the denominator hence the use of IIf to check for this.  Is it possible that Excel is still trying to calculate the

```
FormatPercent(rs2.Fields("SoldCallsQTD").Value / rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value, 2)
```

and throwing the error?  If so how do I get around this or is there something else wrong with this code?

**EDIT**

When I add a watch here are the values I get:

```
rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value : 0 : Variant/Long 
rs2.Fields("SoldCallsQTD").Value : 0 : Variant/Long
rs2.Fields("SoldCallsQTD").Value / rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value : <Overflow> : Variant/Integer
```

Comment: Can't that problem be linked to `Null` values here and there ? THe best way is to get step by step mode and see what your values look like, and/or include a few `debug.Print` in your code.

Comment: Can you check the values of `ActiveCell` (its address), `r`, `rs2.Fields("SoldCallsQTD").Value` and `rs2.Fields("SalesRelatedCallsQTD").Value` when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what caused the error but changing to the following fixed it.  I also created a simple NotNullOrZero macro as checking for > 0 was not enough (Null / Null doesn't throw an error, go figure).  I know the NotNullOrZero is very simplistic but I know all my values are Null or Int so I didn't make it very robust.

```
   If (NotNullOrZero(rs2.Fields("EstimateCallsYTD").Value)) Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(r, 2).Value = FormatPercent(rs2.Fields("EstimateSalesYTD").Value / rs2.Fields("EstimateCallsYTD").Value, 2)
   Else
      ActiveCell.Offset(r, 1).Value = "--"
   End If


Public Function NotNullOrZero(aValue As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Returns true if the value is not null and greater than zero

    If Not IsNull(aValue) Then
       If (aValue > 0) Then
           NotNullOrZero = True
       End If
    End If

    NotNullOrZero = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 arguments of an `IIf` are evaluated before the test is actually done. You can try it with the code below for example, which will return a division by zero. However the error you get is not a "Division by 0" but an "Overflow" error so this is not the only problem.

```
Public Sub test()

  Dim a As Long
  Dim b As Long

  a = IIf(b = 0, 1, 1 / b)

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the optimal way to check for the division by zero?  Is a simple If(b > 0) Then do the work sufficient?

Comment: @BrianKE yes, use a conventional `If b=0 Then a = 1 Else a = 1/b End If`